# Linq: Select data into multiple Lists

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

How can I select the result of a query into multiple Lists?  For example,

```
class Person 
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}

void test()
{
   var query =
     from i in Persons
     select i;

   // now i want to select two lists - list of first names, and list of last names

   // approach 1 - run query twice?
   List<string> f = query.Select( i=>i.FirstName).ToList();
   List<string> l = query.Select( i=>i.LastName).ToList();

   // approach 2 - turn it into a list first, and break it up
   List<Person> p = query.ToList();
   List<string> f = p.Select( i=>i.FirstName).ToList();
   List<string> l = p.Select( i=>i.LastName).ToList();
}
```

Problem with approach 1 is I need to run the query twice.
Problem with approach 2 is I use twice the memory.  When the data set is huge, it may become an issue.

Comment: If the data set is huge, any query will be an issue. Is the data set ever going to get "huge"?

Comment: How do you intend to use these lists? Perhaps it's not necessary to make 2 separate lists.

Comment: yes, it is necessary.  the result will be supplied into another API as two lists.

Answer (score 5):

> Problem with approach 1 is I need to run the query twice. Problem with approach 2 is I use twice the memory. When the data set is huge, it may become an issue.

Either of these tradeoffs may be adequate, but it depends on the resulting dataset and use case.

If you want to avoid this tradeoff entirely, however, you can.  The way around this is to not use Linq:

```
var firstNames = new List<string>();
var lastNames = new List<string>(); 
foreach(var person in query)
{
   firstNames.Add(person.FirstName);
   lastNames.Add(person.LastName);
}
```

This avoids two queries as well as the "copy" of the items, as you only enumerate the query results once, and don't store any extra information.

Comment: Interesting- why the downvoting?  This does handle both of the issues presented.

Comment: Probably down voted because you didn't use the the `SelectAndAddToMultipleCollections` method in the Linq namespace.

Comment: @MetroSmurf True - suppose the built in functions are always better :D

Comment: this solution covers Person and two of its Properites only.  Is there a more generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem with approach 2 is I use twice the memory.

Wrong.  Measure it.  The string instances are reused.